# Index Out of Range in a List

Tags: python, list, csv, indexoutofrangeexception

I have the following python code which should be able to read a .csv file with cities and their coordinates. The .csv file is in the form of:

```
name,x,y
name,x,y
name,x,y
```

However, I am getting the error '**list index out of range**' at line 764:

```
 758 """function to calculate the route for files in data folder with coordinates"""
 759 start_time = time.time()
 760 f = open(csv_name, "r")
 761 f.readline()
 762 f.readline()
 763 f.readline()
 764 lines = int(f.readline().split()[2])
 765 f.readline()
 766 f.readline()
```

The file has around 50 rows. What may be causing the problem? Thanks!

Comment: You should state the separator in the `split`command. You can change it to `split(',')` in order to split the line using comma as a delimiter.

Comment: Suppose the line doesn't split into 3 things or you came to the end of file and readline returned an empty string?

Comment: I just did that. split(','). It gave me the same error, though now it gives me "Read 'cities.csv': 1/2801 lines" and immediately that error again.

Comment: @KoralpCatalsakal is right.  Try `"name,x,yz".split()` in the python shell. You'll get `['name,x,yz']`, a list with a single item. And `help(str.split)` is helpful because it tells you about all of the paramters: sep; _None (the default value) means split according to any whitespace, and discard empty strings from the result._

Comment: You say its a file of `name,x,y` but then you discard several lines then then get one that apparently has a line count in the third position of a split string... suggesting this isn't `name,x,y` after all. You could read and print that line before processing to see what it is: `line = f.readline();print(repr(line));lines = int(line.split()[2])`. That would print what you got so you can see if the split is the right thing to do.

Comment: I tried doing that and it gave me '1,6734,1453\n'. This is the very first row of the file, the name of the city is '1', the x-co. is 6734 and y-co. is 1453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the specific line the program is reading doesn't contain any white-spaces, calling

```
f.readline().split()
```

will return

```
['name,x,y']
```

and so the only index available is `0`.

I believe what you want to do is split each string by commas, if that's the case:

```
f.readline().split(',')
```

will do just that.

Comment: I tried doing that, but then another error came up with this line: tmp = City("C" + str(c[0]), float(c[1]), float(c[2])). I think it is something to do with the split...

Answer (score 1):

The code, `f.readline()` returns a string and splitting it returns a list of the only string obtained from readline() function.

Example:

```
f=open('property.csv', "r")
f.readline()
lines = f.readline().split()
print(lines)
```

Output: ['10001000,104,PUTNAM,Y,3,2,100']

Also, `f.readline().split()[0]` would give 10001000,104,PUTNAM,Y,3,2,100 as a string.
So, `f.readline().split()` will only have 1 element which will be a string type. To separate the string into columns of the csv file,split the string with **comma** as a separator. In your case, replace line 764 with the following:

```
lines=int(f.readline().split(',')[2])
```

Note that : It was index out of range error as the code tried to access 2nd element of a list with only one element as a string.